# process.existed() not getting fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

Hi can some body help me how to call process.existed() method in c#?

Actually i registered that method in page load it self only but it is not getting fired may i know the reason?

```
myprocess.Exited += new EventHandler(myprocess_Exited);

void myprocess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        lblmsg.Text = "Process end...";
    }
```

Thank you,
Nagu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't set

```
myprocess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

(See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) for more details.)